# Python Sql code error - sqlite3.OperationalError: too many SQL variables

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying the below code but i am getting error

```
if not os.path.isfile('train.db'):
    disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///train.db')
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    chunksize = 15000
    j = 0
    index_start = 1
    for df in pd.read_csv('final_features.csv', names=['Unnamed: 0','id','is_duplicate','cwc_min','cwc_max','csc_min','csc_max','ctc_min','ctc_max','last_word_eq','first_word_eq','abs_len_diff','mean_len','token_set_ratio','token_sort_ratio','fuzz_ratio','fuzz_partial_ratio','longest_substr_ratio','freq_qid1','freq_qid2','q1len','q2len','q1_n_words','q2_n_words','word_Common','word_Total','word_share','freq_q1+q2','freq_q1-q2','0_x','1_x','2_x','3_x','4_x','5_x','6_x','7_x','8_x','9_x','10_x','11_x','12_x','13_x','14_x','15_x','16_x','17_x','18_x','19_x','20_x','21_x','22_x','23_x','24_x','25_x','26_x','27_x','28_x','29_x','30_x','31_x','32_x','33_x','34_x','35_x','36_x','37_x','38_x','39_x','40_x','41_x','42_x','43_x','44_x','45_x','46_x','47_x','48_x','49_x','50_x','51_x','52_x','53_x','54_x','55_x','56_x','57_x','58_x','59_x','60_x','61_x','62_x','63_x','64_x','65_x','66_x','67_x','68_x','69_x','70_x','71_x','72_x','73_x','74_x','75_x','76_x','77_x','78_x','79_x','80_x','81_x','82_x','83_x','84_x','85_x','86_x','87_x','88_x','89_x','90_x','91_x','92_x','93_x','94_x','95_x','0_y','1_y','2_y','3_y','4_y','5_y','6_y','7_y','8_y','9_y','10_y','11_y','12_y','13_y','14_y','15_y','16_y','17_y','18_y','19_y','20_y','21_y','22_y','23_y','24_y','25_y','26_y','27_y','28_y','29_y','30_y','31_y','32_y','33_y','34_y','35_y','36_y','37_y','38_y','39_y','40_y','41_y','42_y','43_y','44_y','45_y','46_y','47_y','48_y','49_y','50_y','51_y','52_y','53_y','54_y','55_y','56_y','57_y','58_y','59_y','60_y','61_y','62_y','63_y','64_y','65_y','66_y','67_y','68_y','69_y','70_y','71_y','72_y','73_y','74_y','75_y','76_y','77_y','78_y','79_y','80_y','81_y','82_y','83_y','84_y','85_y','86_y','87_y','88_y','89_y','90_y','91_y','92_y','93_y','94_y','95_y'], chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True, encoding='utf-8', ):
        df.index += index_start
        j+=1
        print('{} rows'.format(j*chunksize))
        df.to_sql('data', disk_engine, if_exists='append')
        index_start = df.index[-1] + 1
```

This is the o/p that i am getting

```
    15000 rows
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1192                         parameters,
-> 1193                         context)
   1194         except BaseException as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    506     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 507         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    508 

OperationalError: too many SQL variables

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-b376654c990a> in <module>()
     14         j+=1
     15         print('{} rows'.format(j*chunksize))
---> 16         df.to_sql('data', disk_engine, if_exists='append')
     17         index_start = df.index[-1] + 1

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
   2125     ...     df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
   2126 
-> 2127     ExcelWriter can also be used to append to an existing Excel file:
   2128 
   2129     >>> with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    448     index=True,
    449     index_label=None,
--> 450     chunksize=None,
    451     dtype=None,
    452     method=None,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype)
   1147 
   1148     @staticmethod
-> 1149     def _query_iterator(
   1150         result, chunksize, columns, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, parse_dates=None
   1151     ):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in insert(self, chunksize)
    661         ----------
    662         conn : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlalchemy.engine.Connection
--> 663         keys : list of str
    664            Column names
    665         data_iter : generator of list

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter)
    636         return str(CreateTable(self.table).compile(self.pd_sql.connectable))
    637 
--> 638     def _execute_create(self):
    639         # Inserting table into database, add to MetaData object
    640         self.table = self.table.tometadata(self.pd_sql.meta)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params)
    946             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(object)
    947         else:
--> 948             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
    949 
    950     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
    267     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
    268         if self.supports_execution:
--> 269             return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    270         else:
    271             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
   1058             compiled_sql,
   1059             distilled_params,
-> 1060             compiled_sql, distilled_params
   1061         )
   1062         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1198                 parameters,
   1199                 cursor,
-> 1200                 context)
   1201 
   1202         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1411                 util.raise_from_cause(
   1412                     sqlalchemy_exception,
-> 1413                     exc_info
   1414                 )
   1415             else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in raise_from_cause(exception, exc_info)
    201     exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = exc_info
    202     cause = exc_value if exc_value is not exception else None
--> 203     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
    204 
    205 if py3k:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb, cause)
    184             value.__cause__ = cause
    185         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 186             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    187         raise value
    188 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1191                         statement,
   1192                         parameters,
-> 1193                         context)
   1194         except BaseException as e:
   1195             self._handle_dbapi_exception(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    505 
    506     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 507         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    508 
    509     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):
```

I have already tried with various chunksize values but it won't worked. Can anyone please suggest me to fix this error. I am running this code in jupyter notebook. I already have updated versions of pandas and other libraries so there is no compatability issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to the number of parameters being passed to sqlite3. In essence, what's happening behind the scenes is that there's a SQL query being issued to the db engine: `INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2, col3,..., col_n) VALUES (?, ?, ?,..., ?)`, where the `?` are the values from your dataframe being passed to the database.

This error occurred because your dataframe is very wide (has lots of columns), so during insertion, many parameters are being passed into the SQL statement. You can actually see in the error stack that justifies my explanation:

```
--> 507         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

Simply, SQLite can only handle a limited number of parameters being passed. This is simply a limitation of SQLite. You can scroll down to #9 in this [page](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) for more info on this.

Setting chunksize will not resolve your problem. My suggestion is using another db like postgres or mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a few tests, I'm not sure that the @Scratch'N'Purr answer is completely correct.

For instance, define a SQLite table with, say, 58 columns.
Then, try to insert a Pandas df with only, say, 830 rows and 58 columns, with a statement like:

```
df.to_sql("tableName", conn, if_exists="append", index=False, method="multi")
```

You will get the op error:
sqlite3.OperationalError: too many SQL variables

I also read that there is an error on

```
"line 2143, in _execute_insert_multi
    conn.execute(self.insert_statement(num_rows=len(data_list)), flattened_data)"
```

I'm not an expert there, but maybe (could someone enlight me on that?) all the placeholders for every row that must be inserted end up in the same query "flattened"?
As a result, we end up with more placeholders than SQLite can accept.

In my case, by modifying the query and setting a chunksize limit, I could get rid off the error:

```
df.to_sql("tableName", conn, if_exists="append", chunksize=100, index=False, method="multi")
```

From that, I must infer that it does impact the number of placeholders used in the query.
So, yes, it seems that the chuncksize could, under some circumstances, resolve such a problem.